# Ionic overlay with ios style selector

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, html-select

On creating a hybrid app using ionic, I have encountered the following problem: I would like to create a overlay with a ios style selector, like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. I have the following code:

Page:

```
<ion-item ng-click="openQuestionTypeSelectModal()" ng-model="currentQuestion.type">
    {{ currentQuestion.type }}
    <i class="ion ion-chevron-down"></i>
</ion-item>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.openQuestionTypeSelectModal = function() {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('selectquestiontypemodal.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
        $scope.modal.show().then(function() {});
    });
};

$scope.bindQuestionType = function(item) {
    $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.currentQuestion.type = item.type;
    //console.log($scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.currentQuestion.type);
    //$scope.setCurrentType(item.type);
};
```

Template:

```
<ion-modal-view class="modal" ng-controller="SupportController">
    <ion-header-bar class="custom-modal-header">
      <h1 class="title">Temporary title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="bigger-header" on-close="closeModal()">
        <div ng-repeat="question in questionTypes">
            <div
                class="item item-icon-right"
                ng-click="bindQuestionType(question)">
                {{ question.type }}
                <i class="icon ion-checkmark" ng-if="question.type === $parent.$parent.$parent.currentQuestion.type"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

I have no idea how to proceed here, or if it is even possible.

**EDIT:**

I tried $ionicBackdrop, but had 2 problems.

1: I couldn't close the backdrop on click instead of timer. I read https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backdrop-example/15863 and tried the suggestions, but they didn't help. I created a scope function containing `$ionicBackdrop.release()` but whereever I tried to call it using ng-click, nothing happened.

2: I didn't find any way to put the `select` on top of the backdrop. Therefore, I couldn't try the select. If I put the select in a $ionicModal, I only got a regular select dropdown, not the iOS styled one.

Comment: Don't you try `select` with `$ionicBackdrop`?

Comment: @HarishKommuri I did try that after your suggestion and some reading, but it didn't work. See Edit in the problem description.